# Tabula-py - Table Titles

Tags: python

First time posting here and I did try looking through stackoverflow and could not answer my question.

I am able to pull out all the tables using tabula.read_pdf(). I was wondering if there was a way to grab title before the table as well as the table?

Below is an example of a table i would like to grab the  tile and table.

I do not have any example code as I am unaware of how to do it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phVLY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMEJm.png)

Comment: do u have multiple page and tables or only 1 page and table? Can u clarify that.

Comment: Sorry yes it multiple pages.

Comment: 1) Firstly read all tables from page.
2) Extract all text from pages.
3) Check each table in your table lists, and find table starting row, and find before the text that row. You can follow these steps.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabula-py focuses primarily on extracting tables from PDFs and doesn't natively support extracting text around the tables, like titles directly. To grab a title above a table, you'd typically need to perform additional steps. One approach is to extract the full page text using another library like PyMuPDF or PDFMiner and then use text manipulation to locate and extract the title based on its position relative to the table. This might require some manual setup or heuristic algorithms, especially if your document's structure varies.